# Adding custom user meta to be used in default get_userdata

Tags: wordpress

I am in the midst of building a mobile app and was wondering how can I add a custom meta so I could use get_userdata method to add onto the user array properly. Based on WP Codex, https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata there is a set of default ones. How can I add my custom user meta onto the list so I could consume in the mobile app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function provided by wordpress called add_user_meta().
Based on de info from codex you can do smth like this:

```
$your_user_id = 1; //here you shall pass your user id
$your_custom_meta = 1000;
add_user_meta( $your_user_id, '_custom_meta', $your_custom_meta);
```

So for adding custom meta with add_user_meta() function, you need to pass the user id, the custom meta filed name and the meta field value